ID & Possible Substitutions for Blown Old Vishay SMD Component
can anyone please identify the component "VD20" (Marked SJ 47A with Vishay logo) pictured in the attached images. There are 8 of these similarly marked components still intact on the board. And the 2 remnants of VD20 which were detached from the board looked rectangular and of the same size as VD13 thru VD16, VD18, VD19, VD23 and VD24. From what I have scraped off the internet it seems to be a TVSS (Transient Voltage Surge Suppressor) or maybe a rectifier diode? I pulled up 2 datasheets from Vishay for the respective components but found that the marking "SJ" matches to a rectifier?
TVSS https://www.vishay.com/docs/88394/smcj.pdf
Rectifier https://www.vishay.com/docs/88711/s1.pdf
The PCB shown is from an Eaton (formerly MGE) 800VA UPS, circa 2004, so I'm leaning towards these components being TVSSs but not sure. I didn't notice the blown suspect component until removing the board to replace 2 blown capacitors on the top side of the board. Assuming the orientation of the blown component is the same as the others I noticed that its cathode connects to a relay and the trace looks to have overheated by the looks of the mark on the top side of the board, maybe I should also test the relay too?
I'm quite confused as to what this burned part is right now but I'm hoping someone can shed some light and suggest a substitute. Any suggestions and or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Addendum: the dimensions (measured with callipers) of the component in question are as follows:
Length = 4.17 mm
Width = 2.61 mm
Height = 2.12 mm


YoungDiode - Hi, You posted an answer to reply to another answer. However, Stack Exchange has different rules from typical forums (please see the [tour] & [help]) so that post was converted into a comment on the answer you were replying to. || Please see the article in the [help] called: "What should I do when someone answers my question?". If your question has been solved, consider upvoting useful answers & consider áccepting your choice of the best answer. Or if you need clarification of an answer, you can comment below it. TY

The Vishay Diodes Group Body Marking suggests:

SJ is the Type Code
47A is the Date code (first 2 characters) and the 3rd character is the optional Factory designator

The ultimate SMD marking codes database filtered on a marking of SJ shows the following possible Vishay devices:



Part number
Package
Description
Datasheet




MSE1PJ
DO-219AD
Diode Rectifier, 600V, 1A, Vf<1.1V(3A)
mse1pj.pdf


S1J
DO-214AC
Diode Rectifier, 600V, 1A, Vf<1.1V(1A)
s1.pdf


S1PJ
DO-220AA
Diode Rectifier, 600V, 1A, Vf<1.1V(1A)
s1pb.pdf


S2J
DO-214AA
Diode Rectifier, 600V, 1.5A, Vf<1.15V(1.5A)
s2a.pdf


S3J
DO-214AB
Diode Rectifier, 600V, 3A, Vf<1.15V(2.5A)
s3a.pdf



From the pictures in the question I'm not sure of the device dimensions, to be able to narrow down which of the above Vishay devices is used on the board. An edit to the question to include some measurements could help to determine the exact device part number, and therefore the specifications to look for in a replacement device.

Thank you for your analysis Chester. I borrowed digital callipers and posted the dimensions which will hopefully narrow down a potential substitute. I've noticed from your listing of potential matches that there is a large variation in terms of size of these devices. I've been combing through my and my friends junk PCB piles seeing if I could find a potential replacement but no such luck. Thanks also for referencing the Ultimate SMD marking codes database, I'm sure I'll be able to make use of this in the future.

as per your list of data sheets on potential matches S2J is the best match for these TVSS SMD components. Thank you very much for your help on this again. Robert
